# gnuplot pm3d and splot heat map with disorganised data

Tags: gnuplot

I used to make nice `pm3d` maps with gnuplot with a simple code like this:

```
set pm3d map
set palette
splot data using 1:2:3
```

But that had `data` organized as follows:

```
1 1 1
1 2 1
1 3 2

2 1 1
2 2 3
2 3 4

3 1 1
3 2 1
3 3 3
```

I never really understood the need for line break here but it worked. Now my data is quite different, the data in the first and second columns are not as simply repeated they are like this:

```
1.1 -1 2
1.2 3 3
1.11 4 4
...
```

I don't have any line breaks there since i have not idea how i should organise them. The question is, how would i make a heatmap from this? (rounding is not a good option)

Some sample data can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/DT0C2rxt). They were created from an original 21x21 array (see below).

### Some background

Originally, the data were in a table indexed by integers. It was basically a polar stereographic projection of the lunar surface. So i converted the indices to (x,y) distances then to planetocentric (latitude,longitude) pair and then to gnomonic polar coordinates recentered on a different point than one of the poles. I want to display the map as distance (x axis) and azimuth (y axis) (from the new centered point) and some value (the coloring of the map). The goal is to have something that looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The sample data you link to is highly structured, but not on an orthogonal grid.  That is likely to produce artifacts.  If the data were dense enough, you could simply draw each point as a solid block, perhaps with partial transparency.  The example data you show is not very dense, however, so this is probably not suitable. I show such a plot below for reference.

```
set palette defined ( 0 "blue", 3 "green", 6 "yellow", 10 "red" )
set autoscale noextend
set pointsize 2
unset key
plot 'DT0C2.dat' using 1:2:3 with points pointtype 5 lc palette
```

[image]

The closest gnuplot has to dealing with unstructured sample is the `dgrid3d` mode.  This basically uses the data points to assign value to nearby nodes on an orthogonal grid.  Various weighting schemes are available to control how many data points contribute to each node and what is their relative contribution. The result is strongly dependent on choosing reasonable values for the orthogonal grid spacing and the weighting scheme.  I won't attempt to describe all the options here. Please read the gnuplot documentation section on `set dgrid3d`.  Here is a rough stab at it but I would want to understand the data a lot better to choose a good dgrid3d scheme.  I think the sample data is not dense enough to produce a smooth result.

```
set palette defined ( 0 "blue", 3 "green", 6 "yellow", 10 "red" )
set autoscale noextend
set dgrid3d 75,75 gauss 100,25
set view map
splot 'DT0C2.dat' with pm3d
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Just for explanation, the data should be basically angular elevation map as seen from a certain spot. First column is the radial distance, the second is the azimuth from northern direction in gnomonic projection.